# Setting a Bitmap as intent extra causes error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I need to put a bitmap into an intent extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), CropActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Globals.KEY_IMAGE, this.imageBitmap);
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

**E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!**

I guess it is because the size of an extra is limited to 1mb. How else could i get that bitmap from one activity to another?

Comment: Not sure if this will work with your workflow, but you might try saving the bitmap to disk (if necessary), and just pass the path to the bitmap in the intent for the next activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

- Don't use multiple activities here, but instead use one activity, perhaps with multiple fragments, or
- *Carefully* pass the `Bitmap` via a `static` data member, making sure to set that data member to `null` after the new activity has the `Bitmap`, to prevent a major memory leak

Comment: In addition to that I don't really get why one would need to pass a bitmap via an intent. You can always pass the URI where you got it from.